# Is orthonormality equivalent to orthogonality and normalization in a normed inner product space?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

Given the concepts of orthogonality and unit vector in a normed inner space defined as:

> Two vectors $x,y$ are orthogonal if $\langle x, y \rangle = 0$
>
> A vector $x$ is a unit vector if $\|x\| = 1$.

Then, is the following definition of orthonormality

> A set of vectors $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\}$ is orthonormal if $\langle v_i, v_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$, where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker Delta

equivalent to

> A set of vectors $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\}$ is orthonormal if
> $\forall(v_i \ne v_j), v_i$ and $v_j$ are orthogonal and all $v_i$ are unit vectors

The [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormality) page on orthonormality seems to state both these definitions, but they don't seem equivalent to me. Is the inner product of a unit vector with itself necessarily 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any inner product space with inner product $(\cdot, \cdot)$, we ***define*** the norm on that space by $\|x\| = \sqrt{(x,x)}$. For more info, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Norms_on_inner_product_spaces). With the norm so defined, if $\|x\|= 1$, then $(x,x) = \|x\|^2 =1$, and so the definitions are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Morally, yes, they are equivalent, but technically, no. Not unless you specify what the norm is. Usually, in an inner product space the norm is defined naturally by $\langle v,v\rangle^{1/2}$, but that's not the only way. I could define the norm as $2\langle v,v\rangle^{1/2}$, in which case $\langle v_i, v_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$ would not imply that the $v_i$'s have unit norm (they would in fact have norm 2).

Of course usually one defines the norm as $\|v\|=\langle v,v \rangle^{1/2}$, so the two are equivalent.